# Configurable FUSE alternative to AVFS

Tags: linux, file-management

While [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net) allows any tools that work with the filesystem to view into archives, the list of supported file formats is static and limited to archives.

Is there some FUSE filesystem able to execute arbitrary transformations on underlying files, perhaps configured in some `/etc/config/file` or `mount -o options` ?

Examples for usage by `grep` would be to apply `json_pp` or `jq .` on JSON files or `pdftotext` to PDF files.